# OpenShift website not visible after git commit

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, deployment, openshift

I've started with CI app in openshift, made few changes and pushed changes with git. I've sshed to openshift server to check if the files are being changed and the are. But when i visit url nothing have changed.

Comment: That sucks. I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: Did you use `git add <files>`, `git commit -m "Message"` and `git push` git workflow? Are you sure you've pushed all the changed files into OpenShift? Do you use [hot_deploy](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/hot-deploying-php-on-openshift)?

Comment: yes i did use usual git workflow, `add`, `commit` and `push`. Like i said files are on the server, i've opened them in terminal, but the changes are not shown when i go to website link.

Comment: Did you reload httpd?

Comment: it reloads by it self. if i'm not wrong...

Comment: First, it's obvious but make sure you've cleared your browser cache, second, you can check your logs with `rhc tail` and see if there are any errors in your logs. Also, pay attention when you do a git push - if there are errors during the deploy and build process, they'll show up in the console.

Comment: @emmychan what kind of error should i be looking for? `git push` shows no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting the head to the latest commit:

```
git reset --hard (commit sha #)
```

Comment: tried that too, no changes when visiting website URl.